# How do you get a JSON value from json_decode in php

Tags: php, api, jsondecoder

I am trying to access the image string of the JSON array for the logo and icon.

Here is what I've got but it's not working.

```
$FinalResponseImages = $responseImages->getBody();

$thingImages = json_decode($FinalResponseImages,true);
            
$logo = $thingImages["logo"]['image'];
            
$icon = $thingImages['icon']['image'];
```

Ive tried

```
$logo = $thingImages{'logo'}->image;
            
$icon = $thingImages{'icon'}->image;
```

but still nothing.

The associative array of the json_decode() is this below

```
    array(2) {
  ["statusCode"]=>
  int(200)
  ["response"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["logo"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["safe"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["image"]=>
      string(48) "https://assets.brandfetch.io/7fb7161ad320475.png"
      ["svg"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["icon"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(48) "https://assets.brandfetch.io/a407773817604b9.png"
      ["svg"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try json_encode first?

Comment: I just tried it $thingImages["logo"]['image']; and I get Warning: Illegal string offset 'logo'

Comment: can you send me an array of that without json_decode? that i can check

Comment: string(215) "{"statusCode": 200, "response": {"logo": {"safe": true, "image": "https://assets.brandfetch.io/7fb7161ad320475.png", "svg": null}, "icon": {"image": "https://assets.brandfetch.io/a407773817604b9.png", "svg": null}}}"

Comment: The comment above is the json that is output without the decode

Comment: try this one.. i have created a demo of you project and i get this..

$icon = $thingImages["response"]['icon']['image'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the "response" array bit. E.g. `$thingImages['response']['logo']['image']`.

```
<?php

$thingImages = [
    'statusCode' => 200,
    'response' => [
        'logo' => [
            'safe'  => true,
            'image' => 'https://assets.brandfetch.io/7fb7161ad320475.png',
            'svg'   => null,
        ],
        'icon' => [
            'image' => 'https://assets.brandfetch.io/a407773817604b9.png',
            'svg'   => null,
        ],
    ],
];

$logo = $thingImages['response']['logo']['image'];
$icon = $thingImages['response']['icon']['image'];

var_dump($logo); // https://assets.brandfetch.io/7fb7161ad320475.png
var_dump($icon); // https://assets.brandfetch.io/a407773817604b9.png
```

Comment: Honestly I really really thought I had tried that though before I posted the question, I musta had something off though